# Ayuda con clipboard.js y <td> celdas </td>

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, script

tengo un dilema con clipboard.js

Lo que pasa es que tengo un par de celdas las cuales quisiera que **al dar click sobre el campo** de la celda se copie en el portapapeles. A manera de prueba, hice lo siguiente:

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/v1.5.3/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.btn');
</script>
```

Y en la vista

```
<table class="table table-bordered btn-hover" id="example1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php if (!empty($contratos)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($contratos as $contrato): ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="cp">
            <?php echo $contrato->ap_paterno; ?>
            <button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#cp">
                Copiar
            </button>
        </td>
        <?php $data_cliente_view =
        $contrato->id_cliente . "*" .
        $contrato->ap_paterno;?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Lo que como resultado es lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*Evidentemente* **no es practico**, lo se. Pero quería ver si me funcionaria este `script` pero no fue así, si lo hace, pero es este ejemplo solo copia el primer valor que le de click al botón (valla: si copio Perez, después intento copiar Gonzalez se queda con el valor de Perez).

El objetivo aquí es que funcione (primero que pueda copiar libremente todo valor dentro de la celda) y también quitar el botón.
Muchas gracias por darle un vistazo a mi problema...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es porque `data-clipboard-target` hace referencia al ID `cp` y ese ID está repetido en todas las filas. Los IDs tienen que ser únicos.

Pongo sólo parte del código para no complicarla:

```
<?php foreach ($contratos as $i => $contrato): ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="cp<?php echo $i ?>">
            <?php echo $contrato->ap_paterno; ?>
            <button class="btn" data-clipboard-target="#cp<?php echo $i ?>">
                Copiar
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

De esa forma se genera un ID único para cada fila `cp0`, `cp1`, etc.

**EDIT:**
En cuanto a la 2da parte de tu pregunta, para eliminar el botón y que se copie el texto al clickear en la celda, tenés que hacer algo así:

```
<?php foreach ($contratos as $i => $contrato): ?>
    <tr>
        <td class="cp" id="cp<?php echo $i ?>" data-clipboard-target="#cp<?php echo $i ?>">
            <?php echo $contrato->ap_paterno; ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.cp');
</script>
```

Es decir, le ponés una clase al `TD` (yo le puse `cp`) y el `data-clipboard-target` hace referencia a sí mismo.

Comment: me has saldados dos veces en un dia... Woooo mil gracias. Ahora me encargo de ver como quitar el botón :P

Comment: @Dante de nada, ahí actualicé mi respuesta para eliminar el botón.

Answer (score 1):

Tu principal problema son los `id` repetidos, recuerda que nunca debes repetir `id` en un sitio, una forma de generar `id` que no se repitan es utilizar el índice `$key` que provee el `foreach`, luego para quitar el botón solo debes agregar una clase a los `<td>` sobre la cual se ejecute el `clipboard` y agregarles el atributo `data-clipboard-target` respectivo:

```
<table class="table table-bordered btn-hover" id="example1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php if (!empty($contratos)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($contratos as $key => $contrato): ?>
    <tr>
        <td id="cp_<?= ($key + 1) ?>" class="dato" data-clipboard-target="#cp_<?= ($key + 1) ?>">
            <?php echo $contrato->ap_paterno; ?>
        </td>
        <?php $data_cliente_view =
        $contrato->id_cliente . "*" .
        $contrato->ap_paterno;?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
</table>

<script>
    var clipboard = new Clipboard('.dato');
</script>
```

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional:

```js
var clipboard = new Clipboard('.dato');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/v1.5.3/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-bordered btn-hover" id="example1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tr>
        <td id="cp_1" class="dato" data-clipboard-target="#cp_1">
            Vasquez
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cp_2" class="dato" data-clipboard-target="#cp_2">
            Perez
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="cp_3" class="dato" data-clipboard-target="#cp_3">
            Gonzalez
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, efectivamente, me equivoque completamente con los  id´s, aprendo mis errores por suerte (y espero).  :D